# Point, square, and cube program help on C++

Tags: c++, class, point

I've been writing a program for CS class that's supposed to get the X and Y coordinates from the user, as well as the length of a square and the height of the cube, and it should then calculate the area of the square and the surface area and volume of the cube (plus some coordinates stuff but that's not a pressing issue right now)

I've written the test file and it compiled successfully, but I've been getting very long answers for the square and cube properties that are obviously wrong. Can anyone point out whatever logical errors I might have or if I have the access specification and relationship between the classes wrong?

Point.h

```
class Point
{
protected:
    double Xint, Yint;
public:
    Point();
    void setX(double);
    void setY(double);
    double getX() const;
    double getY() const;
};
```

Point.ccp

```
Point::Point()
{
    Xint = 0;
    Yint = 0;
}

void Point::setX(double x)
{ Xint = x; }

void Point::setY(double y)
{ Yint = y; }

double Point::getX() const
{ return Xint; }

double Point::getY() const
{ return Yint; }
```

Square.h

```
#include "Point.h"
class Square : public Point
{
protected:
    Point lowerLeft;
    double sideLength;
public:
    Square(double sideLength, double x, double y) : Point()
    {
        sideLength = 0.0;
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
    }
    void setLowerLeft(double, double);
    void setSideLength(double);
    double getSideLength() const;
    double getSquareArea() const;
};
```

Square.ccp

```
#include "Square.h"
void Square::setLowerLeft(double x, double y)
{
    lowerLeft.setX(x);
    lowerLeft.setY(y);
}

void Square::setSideLength(double SL)
{ sideLength = SL; }

double Square::getSideLength() const
{ return sideLength; }

// Calculate the area of square
double Square::getSquareArea() const
{ return sideLength * sideLength; }
```

Cube.h

```
#include "Square.h"
class Cube : public Square
{
protected:
    double height;
    double volume;
public:
    Cube(double height, double volume) : Square(sideLength, Xint, Yint)
    {
        height = 0.0;
        volume = 0.0;
    }
    double getSurfaceArea() const;
    double getVolume() const;
};
```

Cube.ccp

```
#include "Cube.h"

// Redefine GetSquareArea to calculate the cube's surface area
double Cube::getSurfaceArea() const
{ return Square::getSquareArea() * 6; }

// Calculate the volume
double Cube::getVolume() const
{ return getSquareArea() * height; }
```

Comment: Please post the exact copy of the code you have tried. The posted code won't compile. `Cube(double height, double volume) : Square(sideLength, Xint, Yint)` is not right.

Comment: 'Polyhedron' is too much to type in for a class name:)

Comment: class regularPolyhedrons ?

Comment: _"Can anyone point out whatever logical errors I might have ..."_ _`class Cube : public Square ...`_ A `Cube` isn't a `Square`, that's fundamentally wrong!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - It's a question from an alternate dimension.

Comment: @MartinJames inb4 _from outer space_? ;-) ...

Answer (score 0):

> *"Can anyone point out whatever logical errors I might have or if I have the access specification and relationship between the classes wrong?"*

Well, from our well known 3-dimensional geometry a *cube* is made up from exactly 6 *squares*.

So how do you think inheriting a `Cube` class from a `Square` actually should work well?

You can easily define a `Cube` class by means of a fixed `Point` (e.g. the upper, left, front corner) and a fixed size of the edge length.

If you really want and need to, you can add a convenience function for your `Cube` class, that returns all of the 6 `Squares` it consist of in 3 dimensional space:

```
 class Cube {
 public:
     Cube(const Point& upperLeftFrontCorner, double edgeLength);
     std::array<Square,6> getSides() const;
 };
```